# Nombrar PDF con VBA

Tags: vba

Estoy creando una macro para generar un archivo PDF, pero no sé cómo hacer para darle el nombre en base a unos valores de celda. Os copio el código:

```
Sub pdf()

Dim paciente As String
Dim fecha As Date
Dim año As String
Dim mes As String
Dim dia As String
Dim fecha2 As String
Dim documento As String

paciente = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("n_medicion").Range("c14").Value
fecha = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("n_medicion").Range("c19").Value
año = Year(fecha)
mes = Month(fecha)
dia = Day(fecha)
fecha2 = año & "-" & mes & "-" & dia
documento = paciente & "_" & fecha2 & ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\resultados\informe.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

En vez de que el nombre del archivo sea "informe.pdf", lo que quiero es que coja la cadena guardada en la variable "documento".

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo.. supongo no escribiste vos ese codigo no? porque lo que estas pidiendo, lo estas haciendo en todo el resto del metodo, Me confirmas eso?

Comment: Gracias, @Yussef, me ha servido lo que me has propuesto. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un comentario (que ya no está) me propusieron modificar la última línea por:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\resultados\" & documento, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Y funcionó. Gracias.